# Shell bad interpreter problem

Tags: shell, cron

I moved my system from ubuntu 9 to debian 5 and the cron each time that try to execute a script throws...

```
-bash: ./somescript.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

all my scripts begin with

```
#!/bin/sh
```

any clue ? should I change the shell cron is running ? it is using another shell ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `^M` bit makes me think that your script uses [CR-LF line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#History). This usually happens when you edit a file using a Windows text editor.

To fix it, install the tofrodos package and convert the file:

```
sudo aptitude install tofrodos
fromdos -b /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: great, I'm using this, it worked perfectly. I used a windows machine as backup before the migration, that is why. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have carriage returns in your document (Probably edited with a Windows program).  You need to run:

```
cat somecript.sh | tr -d '\r' > somescript2.sh
```

Make sure that you use a new file name like I did in my example (`somescript2.sh`). You can read this [blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001319.html) for the full story.

Comment: Here, have a UUOC award. :-p

Comment: Well since tr doesn't take filename arguments I figure that is a little clearer than `tr -d '\r' < input > output`